# How can i add a new edit text everytime i write something in the last added edit text (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want that the user can make a list of his hobbies. I dont know how long this list is. So I have a linear layout with an edit text in it and and a button where he can add an edittext in the linearlayout, but i dont like that the user has to click the button everytime he wants to add a hobbie, so i want that a new edit text is added when the user wrote something in the last edit text. My problam is that i dont now how to track when the edit text is no longer empty, to add another edit text
For adding a edit text i have this function:

```
fun addet() {  
        val et_hobby = EditText(this)  
        et_hobby.textSize = 18f  
        et_hobby.hint = "your Hobbie"  
        et_hobby.minEms = 3  
        linearLayout.addView(et_hobby)  
     etarray.add(et_hobby)  
    }
```

and my idea was, that i want to trigger this function, when  etarry.last.isNotEmpty is true. I guess i need a listner for that but i dont know which.
Can youn please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to text changes inside EditText using the following listener:

```
etarry.last.addTextChangedListener(object :TextWatcher{
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if(s.toString().trim().length > 0){
                   addIt();
                }else{
                   //You can remove it if you want!
                }
            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            }

        })
```

BUT don't forget to remove the listener from all other EditTexts in your array when you add a new one, otherwise, you may get a new EditText every time you write some text in any EditText not only the last one.

EDIT 1: 
You may also check if you only have one empty EditText after the current one, otherwise, you will add a new EditText every time you write a character in your last EditText